# How do I pass State via Context to a Route in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

What is the best way to set up a React app with the Context API, that will allow me to provide some global state and methods to every route of the App?

Example: I would like to handle REST and Auth at the top level of the app, so I would like my Components to call request methods at the top-level and have the response data filter back down to the Component level.

And... is this kind of architecture even valid in the React paradigm? (I am new to React)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; [CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqpr1o6w15)

Ok, after a little work, I found a method of solving the problem (I'm new to React), so maybe this is a dumb solution. If so.. provide a better answer and I'll be happy to accept your answer.

**The Solution**

Using the [Unstated library](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated), I can create a wrapper around the React Context API that provides dependency injection. This allows me to instantiate instances that I can pass to my components.

For example:

```jsx
import { Provider, Subscribe } from "unstated";
import CounterContainer from "./counter";

let counterA = new CounterContainer({ initAmount: 4 });
let counterB = new CounterContainer({ initAmount: 8 });

const Red = () => {
  return (
    <Subscribe to={[CounterContainer]}>
      {counter => (
        <div className="red">
          <span>{counter.state.count}</span>
          ...
        </div>
      )}
    </Subscribe>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Provider inject={[counterA]}>
      <Red />
    </Provider>
    <hr />
    <Provider inject={[counterB]}>
      <Red />
    </Provider>
  </div>
);
```

Try the demo on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/k3v3wnzrn7

## Wrapping a React/Unstated Context as a Service

I extended this idea and out, creating a skeleton API Service. The API Service holds state properties such as `loggedIn`, as well as service methods like `login()` and `logout()`. These properties and methods are available throughout the app with a single import in each place I want to use the API service.

I did this by wrapping the Unstated Provider, Subscribe and Instance in the `Api.js` service.

For example:

**Api.js:**

```jsx
import { Provider, Subscribe, Container } from "unstated";

class APIContainer extends Container {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false
    };
  }

  async login() {
    console.log("Logging in");
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
  }

  async logout() {
    console.log("Logging out");
    this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
  }
}

const Api = {
  Instance: new APIContainer(),
  Provider,
  Subscribe
};

export default Api;
```

Now I can include the `Api.js` in any other file as the provider, injecting the instance I care about. In this case there is only once instance, but I can provide a different instance if I want to run parallel tests.

**App.js:**

```jsx
import Api from "./Api";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Api.Provider inject={[Api.Instance]}>
          <Routes />
        </Api.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Then I am able to include `Api.js` across the app, and subscribe to which ever instance was passed down the tree.

**Pages/Foo.js:**

```jsx
import Api from "../Api";

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Api.Subscribe to={[Api.Instance]}>
        {api => (
          <div>
            <h1> Foo</h1>
            <pre>
              api.state.loggedIn = {api.state.loggedIn ? " true" : " false"}
            </pre>
            <button onClick={() => api.login()}>Login</button>
            <button onClick={() => api.logout()}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </Api.Subscribe>
    );
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

Try the CodeSandbox demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wqpr1o6w15

Perhaps a more experienced React devs can chime in as to whether I'm butchering the React Framework beyond all reason)...

Answer (score 0):

You inject the function from Context into the container props:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#accessing-context-in-lifecycle-methods

if you want, you can do that without the context as well, would look something like:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' render={props => <Container {...props} API={API} />} />
```

Comment: That's good to know. I was hoping I could do it once for all routes. But perhaps a better strategy is to get the context only in sub-component of the routes, in the exact place(s) it is used?